# How can I shorten my tic tac toe game?

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

At the moment, it is simply massive. I already reduced the size by about a hundred lines but it still seems way too big...
Would appreciate some help :)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static int turns = 1;
    static int player = 2;
    static char[] board = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
    static char playerSignature = 'X';
    private static void Introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a simple TicTacToe game. Enter y if you have played before and n if you are new to this.");
        string input1 = " ";
        while (input1 != "y" || input1 != "n")
        {
            input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (input1)
            {
                case "y":
                    Console.WriteLine("Alright, let's get started, you are X, your friend is O.");
                    DrawBoard(board);
                    break;
                case "n":
                    Console.WriteLine("TicTacToeRules:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1. The game is played on a grid that's 3 squares by 3 squares.");
                    Console.WriteLine("2. You are X, your friend is O. Players take turns putting their marks in empty squares.");
                    Console.WriteLine("3. The first player to get 3 of her marks in a row (up, down, across, or diagonally) is the winner.");
                    Console.WriteLine("4. When all 9 squares are full, the game is over.");
                    Console.WriteLine("If you have read the rules, press any key to continue.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    DrawBoard(board);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter y/n.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void DrawBoard(char[] board)
    {

        string row = "| {0} | {1} | {2} |";
        string sep = "|___|___|___|";
        Console.WriteLine(" ___ ___ ___ ");
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[0], board[1], board[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[3], board[4], board[5]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
        Console.WriteLine(row, board[6], board[7], board[8]);
        Console.WriteLine(sep);
    }
    private static void Reset()
    {
        char[] reset = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
        board = reset;
        DrawBoard(board);
    }
    private static void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a draw!\n" +
        "Press any key to play again.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Reset();
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Introduction();
        while (true)
        {
            bool isrow = false;
            bool iscol = false;
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;
            while (!isrow)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a row (1-3): ");
                try
                {
                    row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                }
                if (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 3)
                {
                    isrow = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid row!");
                }
            }
            while (!iscol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a column (1-3): ");
                try
                {
                    col = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
                }
                if (col == 1 || col == 2 || col == 3)
                {
                    iscol = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid column!");
                }
            }
            int[] input = { row, col };
            if (player == 2)
            {
                player = 1;
                XorO(player, input);
            }
            else
            {
                player = 2;
                XorO(player, input);
            }
            DrawBoard(board);
            Win();
            turns++;
            if (turns == 10 && (board[0] == playerSignature && board[1] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature && board[3] == playerSignature &&
            board[4] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature && board[6] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature))
            {
                Draw();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void XorO(int player, int[] input)
    {
        playerSignature = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';//if player ==1 dann ps = 'X', else 'O'
        int index = ((input[0] - 1) * 3) + (input[1] - 1);//3 - 1 = 2 , 2*3 = 6 + 2 = 8 für 3 3 | compact layout
        if (board[index] == ' ')
        {
            board[index] = playerSignature;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That spot is already taken! Try again!");
        }
    }
    private static void Win()
    {
        if ((board[6] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature ||
        board[0] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature) ||
        (board[0] == playerSignature && board[1] == playerSignature && board[2] == playerSignature ||
        board[3] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature ||
        board[6] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature) ||
        (board[0] == playerSignature && board[3] == playerSignature && board[6] == playerSignature ||
        board[1] == playerSignature && board[4] == playerSignature && board[7] == playerSignature ||
        board[2] == playerSignature && board[5] == playerSignature && board[8] == playerSignature))
        {
            if (player == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 1, you win!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Play again? y/n.");
                Playagain();
            }
            else if (player == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player 2, you win!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Play again y/n?");
                Playagain();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Playagain()
    {
        string input2 = " ";
        input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input2 == "y")
        {
            Reset();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        else if (input2 == "n")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Close the window to exit the game.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter y/n.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in `Introduction` method, the condition `input1 != "y" || input1 != "n"` is always true the game never start

Comment: yes, I noticed. I fixed that by adding the following at the end of the while loop: `if(input1== "n" || input1 == "y") { break; }`

Comment: @morloq, change it to `while (input1 != "y" && input1 != "n")`

Comment: why does that work better? I don't really get it sorry

Comment: I suppose using "break;" isn't the best idea?

Comment: @morloq  _"why does that work better?"_ A given value can never be equal to two different values at the same time. I'm thinking of a number. It could be equal to 1. It could be equal to 2. It could be equal to neither 1 nor 2. But it can **never** be equal to _both_ 1 and 2. Let's re-read your logic: `input1 != "y" || input1 != "n"` Since it's impossible for `input1` to be equal to both "y" and "n" at the same time, this means that at least one of these is always true; and when you use `||` and at least one value is `true`, then the result is always `true`. It helps to work this out on paper.

Comment: You can always check other TT implementations in C# : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe+c%23

Comment: Frame challenge: the aim of improving your code is not to shorten it. Shortening _might_ be what happens when the code gets improved, but it also might not be. Line count is not a good measure for code quality and should not be the ultimate goal of a code review.

Comment: @Flater, using break as I mentioned would be a bad idea? Or is considered bad practice as the while loop is ineffective to begin with?

Comment: @morloq: Your `break` is a band aid on a bad logical construct. It is better to fix the bad logical construct as opposed to relying on the band aid. Even if it works, it's very unreadable and needlessly complicates your code.

Comment: @Flater, so as input1 != "y" || input1 != "n" is always true, the loop executes endlessly right? But input1 != "y" || input1 != "n"  is always false since it is impossible for input1 to cover both at the same time? So if it is always false, why doesn't it execute endlessly as well?

Comment: @morloq: You're not reading your code correctly. What you _say_ would match with `input1 == "y" || input1 == "n"`, but your code uses `!=`. To alleviate this confusion, it's better to work this out for yourself. Manually figure out what `input1 != "y" || input1 != "n"` results in when `input1` is equal to "a". Then work it out for `input1` equal to "y".  Then work it out for `input1` equal to "n". You'll notice that it is always true. Now ask yourself for which value of `input1` you expect your logic to be `false`. Then test with that value. You will _never_ find a value that returns false.

Comment: sorry, I meant whether`input1 != "y" && input1 != "n"` is always false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that we need to address before we can start looking at ways to simplify the code.

As already mentioned in the comments, you should modify the following line in `Introduction` to prevent an infinite loop:

```
while (input1 != "y" && input1 != "n")
```

There is another problem with `XorO`. This checks if the space is empty but the program does not do anything with this information and just continues. I would suggest that you modify it to the following:

```
private static bool XorO(int player, int[] input)
{
    playerSignature = player == 1 ? 'X' : 'O';
    int index = ((input[0] - 1) * 3) + (input[1] - 1);
    if (board[index] == ' ')
    {
        board[index] = playerSignature;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That spot is already taken! Try again!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then modify `Main` with `GetNumber` as suggested by @Ibram to the following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Introduction();
    while (true)
    {
        int row = GetNumber(1, 3, "Choose a row (1-3): ");
        int col = GetNumber(1, 3, "Choose a col (1-3): ");
        int[] input = { row, col };
        if (XorO(player, input) == true)
        {
            DrawBoard(board);
            // ...
            player = player == 1 ? 2 : 1;
        }
    }
}
```

## void Win()

Here you could have created a variable with a smaller name just to make it a bit more readable. You are also missing some parenthesis in some of the comparisons.

You also do not need separate code to write the messages for players 1 and 2:

```
private static void Win()
{
    char sig = playerSignature;
        // rows
    if ((board[0] == sig && board[1] == sig && board[2] == sig) ||
        (board[3] == sig && board[4] == sig && board[5] == sig) ||
        (board[6] == sig && board[7] == sig && board[8] == sig) ||
        // columns
        (board[0] == sig && board[3] == sig && board[6] == sig) ||
        (board[1] == sig && board[4] == sig && board[7] == sig) ||
        (board[2] == sig && board[5] == sig && board[8] == sig) ||
        // diagonals
        (board[0] == sig && board[4] == sig && board[8] == sig) ||
        (board[6] == sig && board[4] == sig && board[2] == sig))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations Player {0}, you win!\n", player);
        Console.WriteLine("Play again? y/n.");
        Playagain();
    }
}
```

## Program structure

Think of your `Main` function as the scaffolding of your program. I would suggest that you try to implement it around the following functions:

```
public static void PlayGame()
{
    InitGame();
    bool done = false;
    char player = 'X';
    while (done == false)
    {
        PrintBoard();
        GetInput(player);
        UpdateBoard();
        if (CheckWin(player))
        {
            PrintWinMessage(player);
            done = true;
        }
        else if (CheckDraw())
        {
            PrintDrawMessage(player);
            done = true;
        }
        player = TogglePlayer(player);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    PrintWelcomeMessage();
    if (PromptNewUser() == true)
        PrintInstructions();
    bool newgame = true;
    while (newgame)
    {
        PlayGame();
        newgame = PromptNewGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh I think I get it now. So lets say instead I use what you proposed ( && instead of ||), that turns false as soon as the users enters y or n right? and therefore the loop ends. so at the beginning of the while loop the condition willl be true as input1 is still empty and therefore neither n or y. But after entering something it will eventually be n or y and so the condition of the while loop will turn false and the loop ends?

Comment: @morloq, That is it!.

Answer (score 2):

The following piece has a redundant logic and violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
bool isrow = false;
bool iscol = false;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
while (!isrow)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a row (1-3): ");
    try
    {
        row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
    }
    if (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 3)
    {
        isrow = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid row!");
    }
}
while (!iscol)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a column (1-3): ");
    try
    {
        col = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3.");
    }
    if (col == 1 || col == 2 || col == 3)
    {
        iscol = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid column!");
    }
}
```

you can reduce to the following

```
int row = GetNumber(1,3, "Choose a row (1-3): ");
int col = GetNumber(1,3, "Choose a column (1-3): ");
```

by introducing the following method

```
static int GetNumber(int min,int max,string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    int input = 0;
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a number between {min} and {max}.");
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    if(input < min || input > max)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid input, input should be between [{min},{max}]");
        return GetNumber(min, max, message);
    }
    return input;
}
```

---

you represent a player turn as an integer this lead to a lot of creepy plain number in your code, plain number are not good for reading you should avoid them as possible it will be better if you represent a player as enum

```
 enum Player
 {
     X_Player ,
     O_Player
 };
```

and define your current player of type player

```
Player Currentplayer = Player.X_Player;
```

Comment: _"the board is 2D board, so to simplify the calculation you should represent it as 2D array not 1D"_ Strongly disagree. 2D arrays may be easier to reason about in your head, but it does not make it any easier from a coding perspective. Reducing fixed-size (!) boards to a 1D array is a very common approach in game development. If you really want an easier to read coordinate system, you can wrap your array in a neat wrapper, which will be significantly more readably than a 2D array.

Comment: There is a small typo in `GetNubmer`. I also do not think that recursion is the best option here.

Comment: I think there are some pros and cons to using a 1 or 2-dimensional array. I would not criticize a programmer for choosing either in this instance.

Comment: @Flater You are right, I just use it because I thought that tak tak to only played on 3*3 board, I remove it from the answer suggestion

Comment: @jdt yeas it was typo i already edit it .... Yes the recursion choice is not the best, Actually i was going to write super loop but get lazy to write it ! ... and it's okay to use recursion because how many times' user will make this mistake .. And the original point was to state Dry principle

Comment: Recursion can get dangerous pretty quickly like in [this](https://tio.run/##rZA9D8IgEIb3/oqLEx1sU1fjosbJwejgXOlpSPBQoG2M8bdXaO2Hujh4CQSO9z2eO27G3IiqAheFEhnsUCK3q5y4FYpYGPiXe737WCgySmK018LiWhCyUeOABKwCjWkGSsPEX0qvGYXTzizIunXJLcz8Odqk2iBrS26dt64YDi1HYC/LDJKwy/vwhuWcDdQoDb5Jasxe8wiCrtHW/dFgbgSdoEg1cEWOk7CE3VU6SMJmJC5vrHaqwcdxDFHUdG/Tg@whPsf5zdEh/hHkrDJxvP2GUlVP) example. Not really relevant to tick-tac-toe, but something to be mindful of =)